# How to parse a big rdf file in rdf4j

Tags: java, parsing, rdf4j

I want to parse a huge file in RDF4J using the following code but I get an exception due to parser limit;

```
public class ConvertOntology {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RDFParseException, RDFHandlerException, IOException {

        String file =  "swetodblp_april_2008.rdf";
        File initialFile = new File(file);
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        RDFParser parser = Rio.createParser(RDFFormat.RDFXML);
        parser.setPreserveBNodeIDs(true); 
        Model model = new LinkedHashModel();
        parser.setRDFHandler(new StatementCollector(model));
        parser.parse(input, initialFile.getAbsolutePath());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("swetodblp_april_2008.nt");
            RDFWriter writer = Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.TURTLE, out);
        try {
          writer.startRDF();
          for (Statement st: model) {
                    writer.handleStatement(st);
          }
          writer.endRDF();
        }
        catch (RDFHandlerException e) {
        }
        finally {
          out.close();
        }

    }
```

The parser has encountered more than "100,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.

I execute my code as  following as suggested on the RDF4J web site to set up the two parameters (as in the following command)

```
mvn -Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=0 -DentityExpansionLimit=0 exec:java
```

any help please

Comment: `-DentityExpansionLimit` is the legacy system property, the new one is `-Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit` - but it should still work. I'm not very familiar with the maven exec plugin - are you sure it passes these properties along to the java process?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra with your suggested property i get the following exception  Unknown lifecycle phase "Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit=0". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.

Comment: That looks to me like you made a typo, perhaps forgetting a `-` in front or something.

Comment: still i have the same problem with mvn -Djdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit=0 -Djdk.xml.entityExpansionLimit exec:java. InvocationTargetException: The parser has encountered more than "100,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.

Comment: This was also asked (and answered) at https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues/1875

Comment: @JeenBroekstra sorry but it is not solving in the provided link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the Apache Xerces XML parser, rather than the default JDK XML parser.
So Just delete Xerces XML folder from you .m2 repository and the code works fine.